# Magento 2 how can i change the icon of module in the menu list of admin

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminmenu

How can i change the default icon of my module in admin menu list. If any one install my module then what he will see in the menu list the icon i put there or default icon.

Comment: Clear Answer from http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-how-to-create-custom-menu-in-admin-and-change-default-font-icon

Comment: tried to clear but i want to show this icon to everyone who use my module without any changes.

Comment: @ Raphael at Digital Pianism  how to make icon changes will show to all the user of module.

Comment: Try following this tutorial, it worked for me: http://www.uecommerce.com.br/change-default-icon-for-top-level-menu-backend-in-magento-2/